# Are leaf nodes included in the calculation of average branching factor for search trees?

Tags: search, branching-factors

In the search tree below, there are 11 nodes, 5 of which are leaves. There are 10 branches.

[image: Search tree]

Is the average branching factor given by 10/6, or 10/11?

Are leaves included in the calculation? Intuitively, I would think not, since we are interested in nodes with branches. However, a definition given to me by my professor was "The average number of branches of all nodes in the tree", which would imply leaves are included.

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia:

> In computing, tree data structures, and game theory, the branching factor is the number of children at each node, the **outdegree**. If this value is not uniform, an average branching factor can be calculated.

**Outdegree** meaning - In case of directed graphs, number of edges going into a node is known as in-degree of the corresponding node and number of edges coming out of a node is known as out-degree of the corresponding node.

You forgot the **outdegree** part. In AI we generally draw directed graphs from one state to another, and **outdegree** is the number of paths leaving a particular node. In your graph direction is not given. Also your graph is not symmetrical, but you can still find out the branching factor (with a little difficulty) of non-symmetrical directed graphs as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789400/how-to-find-the-branching-factor-of-a-tree?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). So technically  your conclusion is correct about leaf nodes not being counted (assuming they are the last state from which no other state can be reached - dead end). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the leaves *per se* count, too, but only if they're real leaves, like e.g., checkmate positions in chess.

Such a node has really no children and no further calculation is needed. Unlike with nodes which weren't expanded yet.

*Note that always counting the leaves [provably](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/454646/14435) leads to `(n-1)/n` for every `n`-node thee!*